# BeautifulSoup AttributeError

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape google shopping using BeautifulSoup and requests. Here is my code, it is pretty straightforward:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import lxml
import json

def gshop(q):
    q = q.replace(' ', '+')
    
    headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
    }
    
    response = requests.get(f'https://www.google.com/search?q={q}&tbm=shop', headers=headers).text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')
    data = []

    for container in soup.findAll('div', class_='sh-dgr__content'):
        title = container.find('h4', class_='A2sOrd').text
        price = container.find('span', class_='a8Pemb').text
        supplier = container.find('div', class_='aULzUe IuHnof').text
        buy = 'https://google.com'+(container.find('a', class_='eaGTj mQaFGe shntl')['href'])
        rating = container.find('span', class_='Rsc7Yb').text
        data.append({
            "Title": title,
            "Price": price,
            "Rating": rating,
            "Supplier": supplier,
            "Link": buy
        })

    return json.dumps(data, indent = 2, ensure_ascii = False)

print(gshop('toys'))
```

This throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Maanav/Desktop/ValRal/main.py", line 45, in <module>
    print(gshop('toys'))
  File "c:/Users/Maanav/Desktop/ValRal/main.py", line 34, in gshop
    rating = container.find('span', class_='Rsc7Yb').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Please view the source of a google shopping url to understand my code better. What went wrong?

Comment: So many views, yet no answers :(

Comment: If you try to print `response.url`, this is what you will get `https://www.google.com/search?q=toys&tbm=shop` which doesn't produce any result.

Comment: I cannot replicate your code because going into that URL it asks you to login in google and soup cannot read the page at all.

Comment: @solopiu It doesn't ask me to log in

Comment: your code is assuming that for each product you will find all the values. for example, certain products will not have a rating. so the program will through exception. try to put an exception on title and rating. for example - `try:
        title = container.find('h4', class_='A2sOrd').text
    except:
        title="None"`  also another way for debugging would be writing the response on HTML and see what has been returned. `with open("r3.html","w") as f:
    f.write(response)`

Comment: And what's the sample query your using?

Comment: @simpleApp Thank you! That should work. I'll check when I get back home from work today :)

Answer (score 1):

As solved by @simpleApp in the comments:

Some times, the products on the google shopping listings might not have a rating, or the seller might not have added the supplier name. This would stop the program from running. To stop this from happening, we must use exception handling.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import lxml
import json

def gshop(q):
    q = q.replace(' ', '+')
    
    headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
    }
    
    response = requests.get(f'https://www.google.com/search?q={q}&tbm=shop', headers=headers).text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')
    data = []

    for container in soup.findAll('div', class_='sh-dgr__content'):
        try:
            title = container.find('h4', class_='A2sOrd').text
        except:
            title = None
        try:
            price = container.find('span', class_='a8Pemb').text
        except:
            price = None
        try:
            supplier = container.find('div', class_='aULzUe IuHnof').text
        except:
            supplier = None
        try:
            buy = 'https://google.com'+(container.find('a', class_='eaGTj mQaFGe shntl')['href'])
        except:
            buy = None
        try:
            rating = container.find('span', class_='Rsc7Yb').text
        except:
            rating = None
        data.append({
            "Title": title,
            "Price": price,
            "Rating": rating,
            "Supplier": supplier,
            "Link": buy
        })

    return json.dumps(data, indent = 2, ensure_ascii = False)
```